# Функция не является членом класса

Tags: c++-cli

Функция должна вернуть значение но выбивает ошибку что S(); не является членом Класса

```
public: String^ S() {
    SendComand(SerialNumb);
    String st = Convert::ToString(sim);
    return st;
}
```

вот вызов

```
 textBoxInfoSerial->Text = printer.S();
```

Comment: А что значит символ ^ в "String^"?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, управляемая ссылка.

Comment: А, у вас не плюсы...

Comment: Какого типа у вас переменная `printer`? Нет ли у этого типа тоже "крышечки"?

Comment: Printer printer; это мой класс, нет он без крышечки

Answer (score 0):

```
  Достаточно было просто применить (Using namespace System)
```

Надеюсь кому- то поможет)
Спасибо ребят)

```
    System::String^ S() {
    SendComand(SerialNumb);
    System::String^ st = gcnew System::String(sim);
    return st;
    }
```